# Can I put two divs in if statement and close it with one div?

Tags: php, css

I have following code.

```
<?php  if(ot_get_option('wide') == 'on') : ?>
    <div class="nothing">
     <?php else : ?>
    <div class="container">
    <?php endif;  ?>

    Some other codes


    </div>
```

Can I put two divs in if statement and close it with one div? Or what is the best practice?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see?

Comment: You also could change only class name instead entire div header, is more clear.

Comment: A better question might be "What is best practice?" Personally, I like @manuelbcd 's idea.

Comment: doesn't matter what's in the `if`, as long as the html that gets spit out is valid. if your `if` ALWAYS will output a `<div>`, then there's no reason you can't have the matching `</div>` elsewhere OUTSIDE of the `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can in this case, as there will always be one div tag and one closing div tag.

The only issue you might encounter is if you're using an IDE, it might validate your HTML and give you an error due to that, as it'll see two divs and only one closing tag.

If you want a more "proper" way to do it or you want to avoid what I've mentioned, you can do this:

```
<?php $myClass = null; ?>
<?php if(ot_get_option('wide') != 'on') $myClass = 'container';  ?>

<div class="<?php echo $myClass; ?>">

</div>
```

Comment: It's simpler: `<div class="<?php echo (ot_get_option('wide') != 'on') ? 'container' : ''; ?>">
    Some other codes
</div>`

Comment: Also why close the PHP tag on line one ?

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. It is but I wanted to show all the steps to avoid confusion, also some people aren't familiar with ternary assignment.